# Why is there no CV_32U?

Tags: c++, opencv, integer, unsigned

Why is no 32bit unsigned integer datatype defined in OpenCV?

There exists an 8 and 16-bit unsigned datatype: `CV_8U` and `CV_16U`

As well as a 32bit signed datatype: `CV_32S`

Comment: There is a question on opencv.org: [Is there a reason why OpenCV does not support (CV_32U) 32 bit depth unsigned integer Mat?](http://answers.opencv.org/question/66230/is-there-a-reason-why-opencv-does-not-support-cv_32u-32-bit-depth-unsigned-integer-mat/) and no answer. Maybe they just forgot?